# Read data to memory from S3 before creating Spark RDDs

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have a Python application which uses two sets of data related to each other. One set of data is a bunch of matrices stored in bunch of files. Each file has a single matrix in it. Also each file has associated with it, another file containing the labels of the rows of the matrix. These two datasets have been stored in S3. I would like to do concatenate the matrices chunked into different files and then use Spark.mllib to perform KMeans clustering over the rows of the matrix.

As a small example this is the concatenated matrix:
matrix=[[2,7,6],[3,6,1],[8,0,1],[6,2,3],[1,9,0]]

And we want to cluster the rows of this matrix into two groups. Therefore this is the Spark output:
out=[1,0,0,1,0]

But here is the problem:
I have a huge matrix of image data. Each and every row in the matrix refers to an image. I would like to keep track of the image each and every row in the matrix refers to. So what I need to do (at least I guess I need to do) is read each and every matrix file and associated tag file to memory from S3 sequentially, so that I do not lose track of the tags for the rows of the matrix. And then create RDDs based on the matrix file in memory. I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to this.

By the way I am using Pyspark, boto, and boto3.

Comment: Could you try to be a little more specific in your question? What have you tried and what are you struggling with?

Comment: I did, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around for a way to this and finding no direct solution, I tried this solution mentioned below:

1: Put the row labels and the matrices together in the Pandas DataFrame associating each row of the matrix to its corresponding label.

2: Used Pandas to_csv method to dump the DataFrame to text files with Pipe ("|") as the seperator.

3: Pushed the text files to S3.

4: Then used rdd=sc.textFile(s3n://user@pass:bucketname/*.csv) to create RDD based on all csv files in the S3 bucket.

5. Used data = rdd.map(lambda line: array([float(x) for x in line.split('|')[1:]])) to create RDD of the actual data.
6. Used labels = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split('|')[0]) to extract the labels.
7. Then performed KMeans on the actual data.

Hope this helps.